# Method for reading a string of coordinates and taking out intgers (Python)

Tags: python, list, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

Lets say that I have a string that represents points on the `x, y` axis "`(1,2), (10,20), (100,200)`" what is the best method of abstracting the coordinate integers for numerical analysis?

So this is kind of a two part question --

First which form is the best for math/scientific computing purposes?
(e.g. a list of lists `[[1,2], [10,20]...`, OR two lists `x = [1,10,100] y = [2,20...`, OR dictionary OR some other form?)

Second what is the best Python way to obtain that form?

Thanks in advance!

PS if there is an easy answer to this in numpy or scipy I would love to know, but I would also like to know how to solve it without using either.

Comment: Basically, it depends on what you're doing.  They're all valid ways to represent things, but have different trade-offs.  The short answer is "don't worry about it at first". However, consider the following: Is the sequence of coordinates going to grow? (if so, use a `list`) Are you working with things pairwise (e.g. x0, y0) or sequence-wise (e.g. all of `x`, etc)?  Are you going to be doing a lot of mathematical computations?  Are you working a lot with other libraries (i.e. if you want to plot things with `matplotlib`, things are going to be converted to numpy arrays regardless).

Comment: In "abstracting the coordinate integers", do you mean "extracting"?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change axis after initialize then best option is `list` of `tuple`s. If you want to change valued then use `list` of `list`s.

Advantage of `list` is order maintain in `list`. If you use `dict` then you have to give key as some value and `dict` is not made for order operation. There are ways to order `dict` like `OrderDict` class and all.

Comment: I agree, for me the best solution is the list of tuple.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be:

```
import re
t = "(1,2), (10,20), (100,200)"  
r = []
for i in re.findall(r'\((\d+.\d+)\)', t):
    r.append(tuple((int(i) for i in i.split(','))))  
print r
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of cientific tools(and users) expect coordinate values as pairs `(x, y)`. I think that if you want to be able to change any value use a `list` of `lists` like:

```
[[x, y], [x1, y1], ...]
```

Y you want your coordinates values to be constant use a `list` of `tuples`:

```
[(x, y), (x1, y1), ...]
```